Remove repetitive characters across each other that linked with dash (-)
What I want is to remove any repeated City Codes adjacent to each other separated by dash (-) in SQL Server 2016.
Source data:
ID  ROUTE   LNO
1   JFK-LAX 1
1   LAX_IAD 2
1   IAD-ORD 3
5   MIA-ATL 1
5   ATL-MIA 2
2   SEA-IAH 1
2   IAH-AUS 2
2   AUS-SEA 3

Current query:
SELECT ID, STUFF((
    SELECT '-' + ROUTE
    FROM DST
    WHERE ID = d.ID
    ORDER BY LNO
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Route
FROM DST d
GROUP BY ID;

Current results:
ID  Route
1   JFK-LAX-LAX_IAD-IAD-ORD
2   SEA-IAH-IAH-AUS-AUS-SEA
5   MIA-ATL-ATL-MIA

Desired results:
ID  Route
1   JFK-LAX_IAD-ORD
2   SEA-IAH-AUS-SEA
5   MIA-ATL-MIA

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/uHs-Vx_G

Split your string, then reaggregate. STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG are your friends.

The real problem appears to be your design though; you are storing delimited delimited data (double delimited!). Normalise your design and then the problem goes away, as you can stop duplicates with a simple CONSTRAINT or INDEX.

What is your starting data? Based on the code in the question you have route strings, that needs to be split into pieces. Based on your DBFiddle the starting data is much simpler. Is it an XY problem?

Someone answered your previous question, did you explain that it didn't work and give them a chance to correct their answer before deleting your question?

And your question needs to be complete in itself i.e. needs to show the raw data and your query (as shown in your fiddle)

The original question involved more than just STRING_AGG for 2016 (and therefore was was not really a dup). The prior posted answer was incomplete. I've now posted the answer that I was preparing when the original question was closed.

They're all repeated except the start and end. So don't repeat codes in the first place! (Assumes that each airport code is three characters.)
SELECT ID, (
    SELECT case when rn = 1 then ROUTE else '-' + right(ROUTE, 3) end
    FROM DST d2
    WHERE ID = d.ID
    ORDER BY LNO
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Route
FROM DST d
GROUP BY ID;

But given the long version of the string and knowing that all the codes have the same length and if you have a cap on the number of airports, you could certainly entertain the idea of a long, nested expression like this:
with dataX as (
    SELECT ID, STUFF((
        SELECT '-' + ROUTE
        FROM DST
        WHERE ID = d.ID
        ORDER BY LNO
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Route
    FROM DST d
    GROUP BY ID
)
select Route7
from dataX cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route,   9, 4, ''), Route ))) v2(Route2)
           cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route2, 13, 4, ''), Route2))) v3(Route3)
           cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route3, 17, 4, ''), Route3))) v4(Route4)
           cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route4, 21, 4, ''), Route4))) v5(Route5)
           cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route5, 25, 4, ''), Route5))) v6(Route6)
           cross apply (values(coalesce(stuff(Route6, 31, 4, ''), Route6))) v7(Route7);

or
...
from dataX cross apply (values(stuff(Route + replicate(' ', 100), 9, 4, ''))) v2(Route2)
           cross apply (values(stuff(Route2, 13, 4, ''))) v3(Route3)
           cross apply (values(stuff(Route3, 17, 4, ''))) v4(Route4)
           cross apply (values(stuff(Route4, 21, 4, ''))) v5(Route5)
           cross apply (values(stuff(Route5, 25, 4, ''))) v6(Route6)
           cross apply (values(rtrim(stuff(Route6, 31, 4, '')))) v7(Route7)

https://dbfiddle.uk/wArraPC0

Nice answer. Greatly simplifies things when you can nail down the right assumptions. One note though: The Route calculation might get executed multiple times per ID before the GROUP BY is applied. That is why I performed a select distinct ID up from in my answer.

@TN I was playing around with something yesterday and I thought that using distinct would help and actually it just made the plan more complicated. Mostly I just left that part because it was OP's source data though.

@shawn00 - Looks like I need to backtrack. Since the only external reference from the subquery is the  = d.ID, it appears that the engine recognizes the for-xml subquery as something that can be calculated after the group-by. The query plan appears to be identical between using group-by and using distinct. Neither performs duplicate route calculations. fiddle.

@TN you got it right. Thank you so much. This is what I’ve  been looking for.

Rather than try to write code to search for and eliminate repeated codes after the legs have been joined together, I recommend a strategy that removes the repeated airport codes after splitting the original "from-to" leg values, and before they are joined into the final combined routing.
(I am going to assume that the "_" in "LAX_IAD" was a typo and this should really be "LAX-IAD".)

Split the original strings into two parts at the dash.
Combine those parts with those from other legs forming a sequence or values.
Use the LAG() function to compare each value with the prior value, and exclude any consecutive duplicates.
Combine the remaining codes into a single routing.

For SQL Server 2022 (and later), we could use STRING_SPLIT() to separate the initial leg values and STRING_AGG(), to perform the final combine. Since LAG() cannot be accessed directly in a WHERE clause, we have to calculate it using a subquery, and then check its value in the outer query.
SELECT
    A.Id,
    STRING_AGG(A.value, '-')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.LegNumber, A.ordinal)
        AS Routing
FROM (
    SELECT
        D.Id, D.LegNumber, S.ordinal, S.value,
        LAG(S.value) OVER(PARTITION BY D.Id ORDER BY D.LegNumber, S.ordinal) AS PriorValue
    FROM Data D
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(D.Route, '-', 1) S
) A
WHERE A.value <> ISNULL(A.PriorValue, '')
GROUP BY A.Id
ORDER BY A.Id

For SQL Server 2016, neither the STRING_SPLIT() nor the STRING_AGG() functions are available, so we need to use alternates. There are quire a few examples that use substitution to map the source string to XML elements or a JSON array, from which the component elements are extracted. There are also many examples that use the use the FOR XML trick to combine strings into a tagless XML, from which the combined string is extracted. It is not obvious how to put the two together.
In this case, since the source values have only two parts, the JSON and XML string split alternatives are not needed, and we can split the string using a combination of CHARINDEX(), LEFT(), and STUFF(). (I'm using STUFF() because it is slightly easier to strip the left part of the string, than to use RIGHT() to extract the right part.)
The FOR XML technique for joining strings only generates a single result per query. To get multiple results (one per routing), we need to first get a distinct list of IDs, and then use a CROSS APPLY to encapsulate all of the string split, lag, filter, and for-xml combine logic for each ID.
SELECT I.Id, R.Routing
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT D.Id
    FROM Data D
) I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        STUFF((
            SELECT '-' + A.value
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    D.LegNumber, S.ordinal, S.value,
                    LAG(S.value) OVER(PARTITION BY D.Id ORDER BY D.LegNumber, S.ordinal) AS PriorValue
                FROM Data D
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', D.Route) AS DashPos) DP
                CROSS APPLY (
                    VALUES
                        (1, LEFT(D.Route, DP.DashPos - 1)),
                        (2, STUFF(D.Route, 1, DP.DashPos, '')) -- Strip the left, leaving the right
                ) S(ordinal, value)
                WHERE D.Id = I.Id
            ) A
            WHERE A.value <> ISNULL(A.PriorValue, '')
            ORDER BY A.LegNumber, A.ordinal
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') , 1, 1, '') AS Routing
) R
ORDER BY I.Id

ADDENDUM
After another look, the OPENJSON() string splitting technique appears cleaner than the CHARINDEX() technique used above.
The innermost subquery would be replaced with:
                SELECT
                    D.LegNumber, O.ordinal, S.value,
                    LAG(S.value) OVER(PARTITION BY D.Id ORDER BY D.LegNumber, O.ordinal) AS PriorValue
                FROM Data D
                CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' +  REPLACE(D.Route, '-', '","') + '"]') S
                CROSS APPLY( SELECT CAST(S.[key] AS INT) AS ordinal ) O
                WHERE D.Id = I.Id

The CAST(S.[key] AS INT) is present because key is a string and will not sort properly for values > 9. (Not really needed for a two-part split, but is good practice in case this code is adapted for some other use.)
It is worth noting that this JSON technique is the data contains certain characters, like backslash. This shouldn't be an issue with your data.
If performance is a concern, it is probably better to stick with the CHARINDEX-based string split solution.
All versions of the query produce the same results:



Id
Routing




1
JFK-LAX-IAD-ORD


2
SEA-IAH-AUS-SEA


5
MIA-ATL-MIA



See this db<>fiddle for an updated demo.

Underscore(_) means arnk or surface sector, it should be retained. I am using SQL Server 2016 maybe I clicked 2022 by mistake.

@JoelLeoj -  Okay. In that case, shawn00's answer is probably the better solution. Don't forget to accept that answer is that satisfies your requirements. An couple of follow-up questions: Will the airport codes always be three letters? Will a following leg ever start with a different code from where the prior leg ended?
